# Does a group travelling to the UK apply for their visas together or individually?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

My wife, two friends and I are planning to travel together to attend a wedding in the UK. Can we apply for our visas together or does it need to be done separately. What documents are needed?

Answer (score 6):

Each person must apply individually for a [visa to enter the UK](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa). In the process, you will be asked with whom you are travelling, but there is no group application process.

Answer (score 0):

Guidance on the documents required is here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf